# <div> element visually it's not getting the the focus on the screen on tab click

Tags: html

There is a `<div>` element with child node `<button>` element, when I click on tab `<button>` element is not getting the screen focus. I can say yes, internally its getting the focus (since screen reader is able to read that particular div element). But the problem here is, as a user I am not able to see (visually) the focus on the screen for that particular element.

```css
pthnavHideSortTxt {
  text-indent: -99999em;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  width: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -0.8em;
  margin-left: -0.8em;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="abc" class="pthnavsort pthnavsortnone" title="Sort Menu">
  <button class="pthnavHideSortTxt">Menu not sorted. Click to sort in ascending order.</button>
</div>
```

Comment: We can’t either. You didn’t post any code for us to see

Answer (score 0):

Try with an onclick attribut.

```
 <div style="margin-top : 5%;">
                                <button onclick="document.location.replace('SomeBodyOnceToldMe.html');" style="font-family: Arial; font-size : 9000px; color : green;">SHREK</button>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Actually screen reader is able to read the content of particular div/button element on tab click. But the problem is focus issue, visually its not seen on button element on tab click.

Comment: Could you show us your CSS class "pthnavHideSortTxt"?

Comment: With just the CSS and the HTML you gave, on codepen, there's no problem. You're problem may come from the minus.